# How to prevent bad queries from breaking replication?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

For my personal experience, mysql replication is fragile.
I know that there area many *things not to do* beacuse they could break replication, but we are humans and an error could always occur.

So I was thinking... is there a way to enforce mysql replication? Something that prevents queries that are dangerous for the replication to be runt?

In other words I'm searching for something that saves replication even if I accidentally run evil queries.

Comment: I am using a kind of log analyzer, looking into mysql logs for bad and slow queries and send them to me by email. so I can react very fast, fix the queries and resync the database.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660/mysql-binary-log-replication-can-it-be-set-to-ignore-errors